# Going trough formatAjaxError even if AJAX call return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have this code on jQuery:

```
$("#filtro").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: Routing.generate('searchCompany'),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: function (filter) {
            return {
                q: filter
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.entities
            }
        }
    },
    formatNoResults: function () {
        console.log("1");
        return "No companies found";
    },
    formatAjaxError: function () {
        console.log("2");
        return "No companies found";
    }
});
```

The server side return a JSON like this, for example:

```
{
   "entities":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "nombre":"Ad modi ea."
      }
   ]
}
```

But in the element I always see "No companies found" and in the console it outputs "2", what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what you have is not a jsonp response.... so try to change the datatype to `json` and try

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks that solve the first issue but now I'm getting this error in console `TypeError: a is undefined` what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#filtro").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    ajax: {
        url: '/echo/json/',
        //your response type is json not jsonp
        dataType: 'json',
        params: {
            method: 'post'
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                json: JSON.stringify(json)
            }
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.entities
            }
        }
    },
    formatNoResults: function () {
        console.log("1");
        return "No companies found";
    },
    formatAjaxError: function () {
        console.log("2");
        return "No companies found";
    },
    //since there is no text property in your json, you need to provide this
    formatResult: formatSelection,
    formatSelection: formatSelection
});

function formatSelection(item) {
    return item.nombre
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3h53psfb/)

Comment: I made some changes to adapt your solution to my code and it works but one error remains, see by yourself in the Fiddle you leave, when you click the item it pass as "undefined", how I fix that?